# How to get the number value in this span ? the span is populated dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the value of this span but it gives me an empty result the data are populated by dynamic function and for this reason it cannot be seen any way to make the code sees it ?

```js
function calculatepopulate() {
    let set = document.getElementById('lastC');
    let text = set.innerText;
    console.log(text)

}
calculatepopulate();
```

```html
<span id="lastC" class="day-number"></span>
```

Comment: Well, is the span's inner text already set by the time you call `calculatepopulate()`?

Comment: thanks I put it below the dynamic function and now it's working thanks a lot. please submit an answer so I can give you best answer :D again thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the inner text of `lastC` is set dynamically before you call `calculatepopulate()`.